# Is the Naive Bayes classifier a specific algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I've been looking for the specific algorithm statement of the Naive Bayes but I can't find any. All I found are pseudocodes and implementations in various languages and documentations discussing this algorithm, but what I need is the step-by-step process itself. Maybe I can't find one because Naive Bayes is a general process (by general, I mean there are algorithms that are specified under the Naive Bayes category or something like that). I have to make an enhancement of it for e-mail classification for my studies. Can you please help me?

Comment: You are correct: naive Bayes is a family of similar algorithms, which model things with a deliberately simple arrangement of few random variables.  Also, you may be better off asking this on [the stats forum.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's not even really a "family of algorithms" so much as just a toy model/way of thinking in a classification problem - it means you don't capture correlative information, but all your random vars are assumed independent (number of vars doesn't matter).

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess I'll have to do further research, then. Thanks :)